# JavaFX. Jar не работает в windows

Tags: javafx, jar

Я работаю в Ubuntu в Idea.
Создал JavaFX проект. Из которого затем создал JAR файл, который успешно работает в Ubuntu. Но в Windows не хочет. И проблема с путями. Ошибки выглядят так:

```
javaxf.fxml.LoadException:
file:/c:/path/to/file/Start.jar!/Module/module.fxml
```

Это происходит, когда при нажатии кнопки в программе выполняется код:

```
(Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Module/module.fxml"));
```

Видел я пост, что нужно загружать так:

```
(Node) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/Module/module.fxml"));
```

Но результат тот же...

Мне кажется проблема в добавлении к пути `file:/` а вот как от нее избавиться - не понимаю...
Может при создании Jar артефакта нужно что-то указать?

Comment: в общем то проблема при любых обращениях к файлам, путь к которым я указывал в коде.

Comment: Файл `module.fxml` присутствует в jar? В подпапке Module? Если написать так `getResource("Module/module.fxml")`? (без начального `/`)

Comment: Да, присутствует.

Comment: Без начального / вылетает другая ошибка `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`                                       `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.`

Comment: т.е. без начального слеша getRosource() не принимает строчку

Comment: немного еще по парсил выводы путей... в виндовсе везде добавляется / перед C:/. Т.е. /С:/ или file:/C:/ - вот мне кажется перед С слеша быть не должно.

Comment: только как его убрать?

Comment: Проблему нашел и была она глубже. В подгружаемых FXML в контроллерах, использовалась строчка для получения пути к каталогу с конфигом `Path pathConfig = Paths.get(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());` вот она то и давала ошибку, причем в Линуксе работала исправно...